# resizing div width using HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm building a chrome extension that uses HTML injection to insert my own DIV into a page. I want to resize it but I don't have access to the CSS. Is it possible to somehow force my div to resize it's width using HTML or javascript?

Comment: can you not resize the div with inline css? ie. `style="height:100px"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resize it using javascript like so:

```
document.getElementById('yourDivId').style.height = "500px";
document.getElementById('yourDivId').style.width = "500px";
```

You could also try setting or adding the height attribute via JavaScript as well.

```
document.getElementById('yourDivId').setAttribute("height", "500px");
document.getElementById('yourDivId').setAttribute("width", "500px");
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with javascript or with inline css here's how to:

HTML:

```
<div id="div" style="width:20px;height:20px;"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var a = document.getElementById('div');
a.style.width = '200px';
a.style.height = '200px';
```

Comment: You should make the answer more specific to the question. ie remove the background color style.